# R: boolean OR and double equal

Tags: r, boolean, logical-operators

Say `a=1; b=2`. Why does `(a|b)==1` yield `TRUE` but `(a|b)==2` `FALSE`? What then is a simple way to return `TRUE` if either (or both) variable is a match?

Comment: The `(a|b)` get "TRUE" and the binary representation for TRUE is 1.

Comment: @dasf Can you clarify your 2nd question ?

Comment: to understand what is happening i suggest reading the document "R inferno" (page 49 for instance). www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: I'm looking for a simple matching test for either or both numbers. The reason I say simple is b/c I need to run it thousands of times as a part of an algorithm and so would prefer a test that uses the least amount of time. If there's nothing better I'll just go with `a==1|b==1` for now.

Comment: Yes, there's probably nothing better than `a==1|b==1`. The expression `(a|b)` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether at least one of the two variables is `TRUE` (or different from zero, for that matter). This result can be coerced into a numeric form, which is done in your case by the comparison with `==` to an integer, and will thus be either 0 or 1. Assuming that a and b are integers, the result of `(a|b)` contains no information concerning the value of `a` or `b` other than clarifying whether both are equal to zero or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the numeric values that `TRUE` and `FALSE` evaluate to, they are `1` and `0` respectively

```
as.numeric(c(TRUE, FALSE))
#[1] 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`|` compares two Boolean values.

In this case, `(a|b)` itself returns `TRUE` because the numbers are coerced to Boolean values by turning `0` into `FALSE`, and everything else into `TRUE`.

From `?base::Logic`:

> Numeric and complex vectors will be coerced to logical values, with
>   zero being false and all non-zero values being true. Raw vectors are
>   handled without any coercion for !, &, | and xor, with these operators
>   being applied bitwise (so ! is the 1s-complement).

`==` doesn't work that way, though; it coerces the `TRUE` into it's numeric form, `1`, so `1==2` returns `FALSE`.

From `?base::Comparison`:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

Comment: I see. In that case I guess I'll go with `(a==1)|(b==1)`.

Comment: Yep, that's the normal way to do it. Another possibly useful construction is `2 %in% c(a, b)`, which is logically equivalent.

Comment: I just ran both options a bunch of times and timed them. I think I'll go with the first one since it's more than twice as fast.

    `ptm <- proc.time(); x <- 0`
    `repeat {
    # 1==1|1==2
    # 1%in%c(1,2)
    x <- x+1; if (x>999999) { break }}`
    `proc.time() - ptm`

Comment: Yep, `%in%` does more, so it's slower. Side note: You can just wrap things you want to time in `system.time({})`, which is equivalent to the `proc.time` operations in your comment.